# instagram detect python requests

Tags: python, python-requests, instagram

i using python for web scraping but instagram detect device like:
**Device · Python Requests · x City, x**
 and block connection, 
How could I fix it?

[image: Device · Python Requests]

i try using `fake_useragent` or  `browser manual setting`
**code:**

```
def login(self):
    print ('Trying to login as %s...\n' % (self.username))
    self.s.headers.update({
        'Accept': '*/*',
        'Accept-Encoding' : 'gzip, deflate',
        'Accept-Language' : 'en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4',
        'authority': 'www.instagram.com',
        'ContentType' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Connection': 'keep-alive',
        'Host' : 'www.instagram.com',
        'origin': 'https://www.instagram.com',
        'Referer': 'https://www.instagram.com',
        'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests':'1',
        'UserAgent':self.ua.random,
        'x-instagram-ajax':'1',
        'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
    })
    r = self.s.get('https://www.instagram.com/') 
    self.s.headers.update({'X-CSRFToken' : r.cookies.get_dict()['csrftoken']})
    r = self.s.post('https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/ajax/', data={'username':self.username, 'password':self.password}, allow_redirects=True)
    self.s.headers.update({'X-CSRFToken' : r.cookies.get_dict()['csrftoken']})
    loginstatus = json.loads(r.text)
    if loginstatus['authenticated'] == True :
        print ('Login Success')
        self.login_status=True
        return True
    elif loginstatus['authenticated'] == False :
        return False
```

Comment: Change `UserAgent` to `User-Agent`

Answer (score 0):

Theres a lot of javascript included. With python `requests` you get the HTTP response directly from the webserver. It have to be render in a browser, to get all informations and content from the page.

The easiest way to solve this problem, is to use [selenium.](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/)

Answer (score 0):

You could try different things. Try to copy `User-Agent` with the one of your browser, if it doesn't work probably is because it is using some cookies or localStorage to store the information about logins. Try to inspect cookies on your browser filtering them by domain and copy the values into a dictionary.

```py
cookies = {"key": "value"} #Dictionary as cookies
credentials = {'username': username, 'password': password}
r = requests.post("http://examples.com",
        cookies=cookies, 
        data=credentials,
        allow_redirects=True)
```

Comment: This is way faster than selenium